# time difference with F experession: error

Tags: django, django-queryset

When I try to calculate a time difference between two fields using F expression it results in TypeError. I can't understand what's the problem, especially because there are other examples where F expressions were used to do the same (here: [Timedelta between two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986054/timedelta-between-two-fields))

model:

```
class TimeStamp(models.Model):
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Expression:

```
q = TimeStamp.objects.all().annotate(diff=F('created_at')-F('updated_at'))
```

print(q)

and error reports (not a full report):

```
File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 93, in parse_datetime
match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I use Django 1.8.8 if this matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `ExpressionWrapper` with `DurationField`:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField   
q = TimeStamp.objects.all().annotate(diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('created_at')-F('updated_at'), output_field=DurationField()))
```